# Woo Slider: Limted to 10 Slides- How to make unlimited?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a WooThemes OnePager installed as a theme and the theme comes with a featured slider. The slider can only hold 10 images. I need much more than 10 images as I'm simulating a iBook (for the Ipad) with the OnePager. I can't find where in the Javascript to change this and I don't know how to change it (as I'm not advanced enough with Javascript).

Here is the GitHub for WooSlider with all Javascript files:
https://github.com/woothemes/flexslider

here is the OnePager Theme for download and inspection:
http://sacredstring.com/timeandregan/theonepager.zip

The above site is also the site with the OnePager installed.

In the 'theme-options.php' file there is the code

```
$options[] = array( 'name' => __( 'Number of Slides', 'woothemes' ),
                'desc' => __( 'Select the number of slides that should appear in the featured slider.', 'woothemes' ),
                'id' => $shortname . '_featured_entries',
                'std' => '3',
                'type' => 'select',
                'options' => $slide_options );
```

Any insight much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you seeing the 10 image limit? Somewhere under Appearance > Theme Options? I just installed the theme locally and was able to upload 11 images, all of which showed up in the slider.

Comment: On the left hand admin side bar there is the Menu option - The One Pager - under there is a slew of options one of them being "Featured Slider" here's the URL to it :http://yourWPsite/wp-admin/admin.php?page=woothemes#woo-option-featuredslider

Comment: The theme you've linked to is not from WooThemes, it's from Techipost. I'm not seeing the menu options you've described, so maybe we're looking at different One Pager themes?

Comment: Thanks! My bad this is the WooThemes- http://sacredstring.com/timeandregan/theonepager.zip

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Found it. Thanks nicolekanderson. Simple mistake - I didn't have the correct OnePager on my hard drive and kept searching in the other theme :/ errg

In the 'theme-options.php' file is this line of code:

```
// More Options
$slide_options = array();
$total_possible_slides = 10;
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $total_possible_slides; $i++ ) { $slide_options[] = $i; }
```

Changed possible slides to 30 and it works.